# Isolating pocket casts from scrobble for last.fm

Tags: music-player, podcast

When I play a podcasts on my android phone using pocket cast 4.2.3 I notice that the details are scrobbled to last.fm. It is happening because I have set my last.fm app to scrobble. I want to scrobble every music playing app I have but I do not really view pocket cast as a music app. How can I stop scrobbling from pocket cast?

In last.fm scrobble settings I see that there are various categories of apps to scrobble from

- Scrobble Android Player: Scrobble the built-in Android music player
- SLS support: Scrobble apps that use the simple Last.fm scrobbler API
- ScrobbleDroid support: Scrobble apps that use the ScrobbleDroid API

Where does Pocket Cast fit into those options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last.fm picks up the intents apps like Pocket Casts and Google Music send to bluetooth devices, and hacks that into their scrobble implementation. I guess they figured Google were never going to support them explicitly so that was their only way in. To stop Pocket Casts from scrobbling you'd un-tick the Google Music option in last.fm.

The fine people of Pocket Casts (read: us) are planning to put in a setting that turns off that bluetooth data, which would also turn off scrobbling. We looked into the last.fm API and there's nothing extra we can send to tell them to ignore us, which would be a better solution, since it would mean keeping the blue tooth meta data as well.

Comment: For the past few months or years last.fm on my android has been scrobbling my various music players but not my pocket cast. Something happened on or just before Wednesday 2013-05-22 15:00 (Eastern Time in the USA) that put the pocket cast data into last.fm for the first time. Did a recent release from you put the data in the bluetooth data which then enabled last.fm scrobbler to see it?

Comment: Yes, in v4.2 we added bluetooth meta data, as the release notes say in the store ;)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Farrel, the only way I've found to allow Google Music to scrobble to Last.fm but not Pocket Cast is to stream podcasts rather than downloading them — that seems to work. I realise that this is not always ideal.</strike>

Don't forget you can delete tracks from your last.fm profile/library but I'm not sure if that is persistent. Again, not ideal.

Comment: Alas, I am wrong — streamed podcasts can be scrobbled. Sincerely sorry for reporting otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am pretty late to the party, but [Pano Scrobbler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arn.scrobble&utm_source=share&pcampaignid=share) no longer relies on the traditional music intents. It checks for media sessions only from specific players, which are enabled in settings.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Last.fm app only scrobbles if the device tells it to. 
So i think in you Pocket Cast, if you go in to it's settings then i think you would find something about Scrobbling, and you should have there an option to disable it.

Comment: I want last.fm to scrobble my music player (such as Google Play) but I do not want it to scrobble my podcast player. Pocket cast does not have a scrobble setting.